# rowid and finding duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

table has duplicates:

```
JOB                  JOBID                EMPID              
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Manager              10                   1                   
Manager              10                   1                   
Operations           20                   2                   
Engineer             30                   3                   
Manager              10                   1                   
Operations           30                   2
```

The query

```
select * from  dept
where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from dept group by job);
```

gives results as:

```
JOB                  JOBID                EMPID              
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Manager              10                   1                   
Operations           30                   2                   
Manager              10                   1
```

can anyone explain how does it process to retrieve the result ?
I know each row has unique `rowid`. but first the subquery executes to get the minimum of `rowid` that is the first row and then compares(not in) with the outer one which retrieves all `rowid`'s. can some explain much more clear how does it compare and retrieve 3 rows as result ? Trying to understand the simple logic. ?

Comment: You have tagged this for MySQL and for Oracle.  I am guessing that the MySQL tag is incorrect based on the content of the question.  Should that be removed?  Or is there some MySQL portion of the question that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data you posted, the subquery will return one row for each job - Manager, Operations, and Engineer.  Then it gets all the records not in that subquery.

It doesn't return Engineer, because the only rowid has to be the minimum.  There are three records for Manager.  One has lowest rowid so the other two are returned.  It's similar for Operations.

A rowid is explained quite nicely in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm).

Comment: Thankyou for suggesting

Comment: yeh I got it  realized now